# Redondear un dato double en android

Tags: android

¿Cual es el comando para redondear en Android?, ya que en Java es Math.round.

```
double a = 123.13698;
double roundOff = Math.round(a*100)/100;
System.out.println("roundOff " + roundOff);
```

¿En android que comando es?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar para ambos lenguajes tanto para el lenguaje `Java` como para `Kotlin`  el método `Math.round()`:

**Java**

```
 System.out.println(Math.round(10.0124));
```

**Kotlin:**

```
println(Math.round(10.0124));
```

---

Si deseas redondear con precisión, puedes usar la clase [**BigDecimal**](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/math/BigDecimal) para este propósito, recuerda que es importante agregar el lenguaje en el cual realizas tu pregunta, aquí un ejemplo de como realizarlo en Android Studio para ambos lenguajes:

**Java:**

```
public static Double round2Decimals(Double value) {
    return new BigDecimal(value.toString()).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue();
}
```

Ejemplo de como llamar el mètodo:

```
 println(round2Decimals(10.0124, 0))
```

salida:

```
10.0
```

---

**Kotlin:**

```
fun round2Decimals(number: Double, numDecimalPlaces: Int): Double {
    return number.toBigDecimal().setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toDouble()
}
```

Ejemplo de como llamar el mètodo:

```
System.out.println(round2Decimals(10.0124, 0));
```

salida:

```
10.46
```